# Is is possible to alter brain states to trigger emotions?

Tags: science-based

I would like to have a group of people who have the ability to manipulate other's brain waves so the user could force a target to feel a certain emotion, such as joy, fear, or nausea. This ability would have to work on those who do not have any other functions in their brain to receive the manipulation, and this ability should not lead to the situation with those with this ability would be able to read other's mind.

Assume both groups of brains are human for the sake of the question.

Comment: Probably not without killing someone. Interestingly enough, there's a discussion on this going on in a Discord server I'm in right now. Tldr: ionizing radiation is bad for your gray matter.

Comment: Can you clarify if your question is "How would the manipulator alter brain states?" or "Is is possible to alter brain states to trigger emotions?" Those are really different questions.

Comment: It is known that brain surgeons will wake up patients and stimulate parts of the brain electrically to see what sort of response this gets.  For example, if someone says they smell popcorn, that's a hint that you're near the olfactory part of the brain.  They use this information to make more precise cuts.  Is this close enough to forcing someone to feel a certain emotion?

Comment: @CortAmmon https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_brain_stimulation says they can go a little farther. Also brain surgery generally doesn't involve ever going to sleep to be woken up, only a local aesthetic is used for the scalp.

Comment: Voting to close this question.  It isn't clear what is being asked.  As it's written, the only valid answer is "yes."  Because any explanation as to why is, according to the question, no more valid than any other, the question is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: maybe through hormones injection can be done easily..

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'd like to point the fact that all I'm gonna mention is speculation, my points may be completely shut down by basic physics and biology.

The first thing I think about after beign presented with your scenario is electricity. The human brain uses electricity to "transport commands" through your body, therefore, it's possible that beigns with especific electric abilities would be able to generate, alter or remove emotions and feelings (although feelings are more related to chemicals than electricity).

The usage of electricity would not result in extracting informations (mind reading), as it would basically be a one way discharge.

It's important to notice that this would most likely result in very close-range possibilities, limiting the range of the electrical being's powers to melee range.

Comment: Leading off an answer by questioning your own knowledge probably isn't the best way to go.  I'd remove the first sentence were I you.  Welcome to World Building and check out the [tour] and [help] to get familiar with the site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. We know from studies of people with traumatic brain injuries that emotions happen in one part of the brain, but are experienced in another part of the brain. You would expect stimulating one part of the brain would create the emotions, while stimulating the other would create the experience of the emotions without the reality.

The ability to insert emotional content directly into a person's brain by firing neurons via some sort of electrical field stimulation is both biologically explainable and within the bounds of physics, but the exact technique will require some handwavium at this point.

Comment: pojo, what do yo mean by ",but the physical and biological principles don't rule this out?"  which statement are you referring to?

Comment: The ability to insert emotional content directly into a person's brain is both biologically explainable and within the bounds of physics, but the technique will require some handwavium at this point.  Edited to use this (hopefully better) explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. It can be done *now*, in crude form. Electrical stimulation of some parts of the brain can caused hallucinations (although the subject is usually aware what they're experiencing isn't real), and in monkeys they've been able to artificially create disgust and friendliness.

Comment: Any chance you can elaborate by sharing some background information?  This is an answer yes, but an answer that provides supporting information would be significantly better.

Answer (score 0):

Use Drugs Instead

Instead of messing with their brains by trying to mess with brain waves, this can easily be done with drugs. Depends on how you want to deal with administering the drugs but even discretely spaying it in the air as they walk by can be enough to completely override their emotional state if the correct drug is used. There is a reason why drugs are used much more readily deal with psychological conditions over electro-therapy.

There are drugs that make you high, ones that makes you depressed, ones that completely destroy your sense of reality and ones that knock you out. It is why so many drugs are controlled substances in most countries. And part of the reason why some drugs are so addictive.

Drugs also do not allow mind reading so your concern of that can be eliminated.

Comment: Answers should conform to the question being asked and unless logically inconsistent go with what the OP asked.

Comment: @James Drugs do alter brainwaves even if you want to pedantic about it.